# How to intentionally make a file be "EBUSY: resource busy or locked"

Tags: file, locking

In all my search attempts, I could only find people trying to fix an "EBUSY: resource busy or locked" error.

What I want is to intentionally put a file in this state (temporarily). How can this be done?

I tried using `fs.open`, `fs.createReadStream` and `fs.createWriteStream` from NodeJS, but for my surprise this doesn't make the file busy.

How can I do this? Preferably in NodeJS, but it can be in any language.

Answer (score 1):

On .NET Core, you can use `FileStream.Lock()`.

Here's [the API documentation from .NET Core 3.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.lock?view=netcore-3.1) which includes a sample .NET program also that does locking a file exclusively, which should trigger the `'EBUSY: resource busy or locked'` error in node JS programs trying to access the same file.

The `FileStream.Lock()` API call signature is:

```
public virtual void Lock (long position, long length);
```

You can call it with position set to 0 and length set to the length of the file. `FileStream.Lock()` on Windows allows locking file ranges.

Comment: Cool, is this cross-platform? (Windows, Linux and Mac)

Comment: .NET Core 3.1 is cross-platform (Win/Linux/MacOS and can run on Docker). On the behavior of FileStream.Lock() being identical across platforms -- that's an open question. I don't know enough about the lower level File APIs in Linux / MacOS to comment on whether it will behave the same. For instance: there are POSIX API calls like lockf() that work on all the platforms. I am not sure if .NET uses those on the non-Windows platforms. But, the .NET source code can be compiled on those platforms and you can try it yourself and update this article with what you find.

Comment: Thanks. Another question (I never used dotnet before): you linked to the docs of v3.1, does it work with the newest version as well?

Comment: .NET Core is the cross-platform .NET and 3.1 is the latest version of .NET Core available. It is here. https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download